# Syntax error: unexpected ':'

Tags: php, syntax

I am modifying an existing line of PHP from this"

```
$checkout->setReturnUrl( urldecode( Config::GetInstance()->GetSessionVariable( CC_FB_URLEMBEDDED ) ) . '?action=checkedout' );
```

to this:

```
$checkout->setReturnUrl( ‘http://www.fruitfulfarm.net/fundraiser/thank-you.html?action=checkedout' );
```

I want a specific URL instead of a urldecode, but I get a syntax error that says unexpected ":" in this line.

I can't see why this is.  I'm a newbie at php.  Can someone give me a suggestion for this line?

Comment: Replace that fancy `‘` with a proper `'` and it should work

Comment: It looks like your opening quote is an angled quote `‘` rather than the "foot sign" used by PHP `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your starting quote is incorrect it should be `'`

```
$checkout->setReturnUrl( 'http://www.fruitfulfarm.net/fundraiser/thank-you.html?action=checkedout' );
```